# Why is regular expression notation still written in ASCII?

Tags: regex, unicode

Regular expressions are hard to read. Part of the reason they are hard to read is that they are encoded with a very small list of characters (ASCII).

Why is it that new notations for regular expressions are not created using a broader range of characters from Unicode?

The [backslash plague](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/python/regex/node8.html) results from the fact that a backslash is overloaded: it means, at once, "a backslash" and "the next letter is not itself".

But this is kind of nuts, isn't it? A backslash should just be a backslash, and "the next letter is not itself" should be something which is unlikely to appear in text.

The obvious response to this will be "but whatever you choose might also appear in text!" And yeah, that's true. But the probabilities of wanting to match a backslash (given the history in which we find ourselves) are astronomically higher than some other obscure symbol from Unicode.

Or take brackets: why do we have to write [\[\]] when we could use some other character—I dunno, maybe the East Asian one or something:

```
《[]》
```

Call me crazy but

```
>>> re.compile('《[]》')
```

Looks a lot more readable to me than:

```
>>> re.compile('[\[\]]')
```

There are even [specific characters](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2424/index.htm) for things like newlines:

```
␤
```

I'm not sure that one's terribly readable, but you get the idea right? Maybe it should be

```
↪
```

Or

```
↳
```

I'm not trying to suggest that any of these particular character choices are "right." I'm just amazed that there doesn't seem to be any discussion of this topic, as far as I can tell.

Why are people willing to put up with the excruciating consequences of trying to write regular expressions with a tiny alphabet?

**UPDATE**

Wow, I'm surprised at the derision this question has evoked. What's the big deal?

Since my clutzily messed-up comment below was relevant to several comments, I'll just write here:

With all due respect the argument that "we don't have keys for it" doesn't make much sense to me. How many "special characters" are we talking about here? Let's say at the absolute maximum, 100. (And that's crazy, realistically it's probably more like 20.)

Input methods are not what I am talking about—after all, we don't say to people who want to use their computer in a writing system besides the Latin alphabet that "sorry, those keys aren't on the keyboard"? Of course not.

It's simply *not* the case that we rely on hardware to determine what character sets we compose text with. Those days are gone. Every programming language worth its salt now supports Unicode more or less all over the place, or else is working on it. It will be universal sooner or later.

If the attitude here is representative of most of the tech industry, though, I suppose we'll all be enjoying escaping into the 2050s.

Awesome.

Comment: Because that way PERL programs look cool :)

Comment: You raise a valid point, but as other people said it's not realistic to use unicode characters.  Still, interesting food for thought.  Don't know why you got a -1 for this.  :/

Comment: Perl regular expression syntax allows most any ascii character as a delimiter.  Even allows delimiter pairing. s{foo}{bar}g

Comment: 1. Write a replacement.
2. Publish it.
3. Profit!

Comment: Is this an actual problem you face at work? Or is it a rant disguised as a question? Not to be all 'read the FAQ', but...

Comment: Haha, well, I guess you could implement some kind of IME like they have for Japanese input on an English-layout keyboard, but is it really worth it?  Sorry you feel that way but your question has been thoroughly answered, whether the answer appeals to your sensibilities or not.

Comment: I definitely think there is scope for an alternative regex syntax that involves more readability and less escaping. I'm not convinced using exotic non-ASCII brackets is the way to do that, however (and I use eurokb, so I can type a wide range of Unicode weirdness easily!). FWIW my first move would be to put all literal characters inside quotes, freeing up every other character for metacharacter purposes.

Comment: This is a wonderful idea! The backslash is especially problematic on the shell or in string literals. I'm tempted to have a crack at implementing this!

Answer (score 10):

Do you have keys for those characters on your keyboard?

Comment: That's *exactly* the reason why regexes and programming languages do not use non-ascii character for their basic syntax.

Comment: With all due respect that argument doesn't make much sense to me.

How many "special characters" are we talking about here? 

Let's say at the absolute maximum, 100. (And that's crazy, realistically it's probably more like 20.)

Is it really the case that we couldn't come up with ways

Comment: You little sneak. Post a CW answer. Grap upvotes. Un-CW it.

Comment: @pat: I think it does. Not being able to easily enter things you use on a regular base would be extremely bad UX.

Comment: @KendallFrey: Actually only mods can un-CW. The reason why I did this was because the OP most likely CW'd it since he considered it not a serious answer - however, it perfectly answers the question.

Comment: Kendall, huh? I hit enter by accident. Sigh.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Oh, I see.

Comment: As an aside, don't use normal strings for patterns... python has raw strings: re.compile(r'some\pattern\with\literal\backslashes')

Comment: Just to be pedantic: This `life←{↑1 ⍵∨.∧3 4=+/,¯1 0 1∘.⊖¯1 0 1∘.⌽⊂⍵}` is a valid code — in [APL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language))

Comment: I didn't feel like I deserved any points for this answer, so I switched it to CW.  Oh well~ :3

Answer (score 1):

Because they are even harder to type.

Answer (score 1):

What if i want to use a newline that's just a character and not a newline?

"/\↳/" ?

But nothing stops you for making an implementation of some sort of syntax sugar for regexes, if it works, then you were right.

Comment: It's impossible to make all escaping issues go away, it's a fact of nature. But regex notation was created in an era when hardware really _did_ impose upper limits on the size of the available alphabet, but those hardware limitations have evaporated.

Comment: As for me doing it, I freely admit that I haven't a clue how to write a regex engine. All props to the people who can.

Comment: @pat, do you even need to write a regex engine? Just write a pre-parser that converts Unicode-enabled Regexes into regular regexes and then feed it to PCRE or whatever regex engine you prefer. This should simply be a lookup table of Unicode strings into ASCII strings, with perhaps a bit of knowledge about whether or not you're inside of a ``()`` or ``[]``. EDIT: It would be hilarious if you wrote it as a regex.

Comment: yes, that's why i mentioned syntax sugar, some regexes and lookup tables should do.

Answer (score 0):

Because most people don't have Unicode keyboards.

Do you honestly expect us to fire up charmap everytime we want to make a regex?

Comment: Charmap is hardly the only way to input characters.

Comment: @pat: How would you suggest the average user does it?

Comment: @pat: You haven't suggested any way to make it easy to enter regexes. All the methods I can imagine involve many keystrokes, or complicated mousing. I think the problem is that you are overlooking practical limitations.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with everyone saying that it would make typing the regex much harder. I also think it would slow me down having to lookup characters whereas it's simpler to use backslash which is commonly used in many programming languages to escape chars.

If readability is the main concern, that should be addressed with a comment above the regex.